Does lsp-find-references have some semantic understanding?
Does lsp-find-references have some semantic understanding? If I lsp-find-references on a C# method called Initialize(), it finds 500+ references in my large code base.
Surely, they are not all the same method.
Visual Studio finds 10 references, demonstrating semantic understanding, but doesn't it also use LSP?

LSP is a protocol, a way for your editor to send queries to a type of program known as a Language Server. The editor knows nothing at all about the language, it merely relies on whatever answers are sent by the Language Server. You need to figure out what Language Server you are using and read its documentation to learn what features it has and how it operates.
